# Display a custom map in a MapFragment

Tags: android, android-mapview

Recently, [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) has been released, introducing `MapFragment`. It seems like a neat feature. However, I was wondering if it would be possible to use a `MapView` with the `MapFragment` to display a custom map instead of having a map loaded by the Google Play Services.

Looking at the documentation for [`MapFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html), I couldn't find any methods that would allow to attach a custom `MapView`. Moreover, it seems like you can never replace the [`GoogleMap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html) that is used in the `MapFragment`.

For me this seems like, in order to be able to use custom maps, you cannot use the new maps API. I would appreciate the input of more knowledgeable people on this matter.

Edit: I would appreciate if someone could add the android-mapfragment tag, thereby creating it. Feel free to remove this edit once you have done so.

Comment: could you further explain what you mean by: custom map? You'll create your own mapview from scratch?

Comment: Yes. I have already created a MapView that holds my custom map.

Comment: So why do you want to use the MapFragment? Why not use just a normal fragment with your custom map on it? I'm honestly trying to understand the issue, so I can try to help.

Comment: I thought it might be better to investigate the use of the new API. As the application is still in development, using the new API might facilitate maintenance in the future and lead to a leaner application regarding the use of system resources.